Cannot connect to server on certain ports from VMs not running on same ESX host
We have a Windows 2019 server that has just been migrated to a new ESXi host.
From another server on the same subnet, but NOT on the same ESXi host, we can ping the server, RDP to it, and connect on certain TCP ports, e.g., 135, but we cannot connect on port 445.
From a server running on the same ESXi host, we can connect on all ports, including 445.
The local Windows firewall has been completely disabled and there is no external firewall device between any of the servers we are testing with.
We have confirmed the server is listening on port 445 using netstat, and this is confirmed by the fact that we can connect to that port from the server running on the same host.
Is there anything else at the ESX host/NIC/switch level that could be blocking connectivity only on specific ports?

Is there anything else at the ESX host/NIC/switch level that could be blocking connectivity only on specific ports? - No, there isn't. Run a packet capture on the source and destination machines and filter the capture for port 445. One side or the other should give you some clues. You can also use the portqry tool from the source to see what it tells you.
